# Table below x axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hello everyone I was trying to add some text below the x axis in `ggplot2` and I was able to do so using `geom_text`and with help of `coord_cartesian` but I couldn't make it reproducible as this need to run in a loop. I thought that adding the values I want with the row names (First, Second) in a table would fix it, does anybody have experience in that. below is the workaround I did. Thank you very much in advance.

```
## Data

Grade <- 1 : 20 

Case <-  rep(paste('case' , 1:5,sep = ''),4)

Number <- paste('n', 1:20 ,  sep = '')

Class <- c(rep('Class1',5) , rep('Class2',5) , rep('Class3',5) , rep('Class4',5))

se <- 0.2

df <- data.frame(Grade,Case ,Number, Class  , se)


## plot 

ggplot(df, aes(x= factor(Case , levels = c('case1','case2' , 'case3' , 'case4','case5')) , y=Grade ,
                        fill= Grade)) + 


  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity",
           colour="black",
           size=.4) +    

  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Grade +se, ymax=Grade +se),
                size=.3,    
                width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9))+


  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = Grade , ymax = Grade +se),position=position_dodge(.9))+

  geom_text(aes(label=Number , y = Grade  + se + 1),data=df, position=position_dodge(0.9), size= 4) +


  ggtitle('Place a table below x axis')+

  facet_grid(~Class) + 

  xlab('') + 

  ylab('Case Num') + 

  theme_gray()+


  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,6), "lines"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15))  +

  scale_x_discrete(labels = paste(1:5 , '\n' ,  10:15,  sep = '')) + 

  geom_text(data = df[df$Class == 'Class1',],x = -1 , y = -3, 

            label= 'First\nSecond' , size = 4)+


  coord_cartesian(clip = "off" , xlim = c(1, 5) )
```

[image]

EDIT:

Sorry for the confusion,although the solution suggested by @stefan is pretty much convenient but the main purpose is to have something like this:
[image]

considering that the proposed table will contain external characters, not taken from the data frame at all (if possible!).

Comment: Could you provide a sketch of your expected outcome. I'm struggling to understand what sort of table you want. Also it would be helpful to understand what you are trying to achieve with your loop.

Comment: So your goal is to align First with 1,2,3... and Second with 10,11,12,... and also be able to add Third, Fourth etc inside a loop?

Comment: Thank you Peter and Shan R for the replies, I meant with the loop that the same analysis will be running on the same data frame pattern so I'll get x number of this graph at the end. but all should have the same characters under the x axis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an alternative approach to tackle this problem I simply set up the table as a second ggplot which I glue together with the major ggplot using `patchwork`.

```r
## Data

Grade <- 1 : 20 
Case <-  rep(paste('case' , 1:5,sep = ''),4)
Number <- paste('n', 1:20 ,  sep = '')
Class <- c(rep('Class1',5) , rep('Class2',5) , rep('Class3',5) , rep('Class4',5))

se <- 0.2

df <- data.frame(Grade,Case ,Number, Class  , se)

library(patchwork)    
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

## plot 

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x= factor(Case , levels = c('case1','case2' , 'case3' , 'case4','case5')) , y=Grade ,
               fill= Grade)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity",
           colour="black",
           size=.4) +    
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Grade +se, ymax=Grade +se),
                size=.3,    
                width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9))+
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = Grade , ymax = Grade +se),position=position_dodge(.9))+
  geom_text(aes(label=Number , y = Grade  + se + 1),data=df, position=position_dodge(0.9), size= 4) +
  ggtitle('Place a table below x axis')+
  facet_grid(~Class) + 
  xlab(NULL) + 
  ylab('Case Num') + 
  theme_gray()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())

p2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(First = as.integer(stringr::str_extract(Case, "\\d")),
         Second = First + 9,
         Third = Second + 9) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(First, Second, Third), names_to = "layer", values_to = "label") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Case)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = factor(layer, c("Third", "Second", "First")), label = label)) +
  labs(y = "", x = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank()) +
  facet_grid(~Class)

p1 / p2 +  plot_layout(heights = c(8, 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**EDIT**: Tweak to get a more table like output by adding a `geom_tile` and removing the spacing between facets as well as setting expansion of x-axis to zero:

```r
p2 <- df %>%
  select(Case, Class) %>% 
  mutate(First = letters[1:nrow(.)],
         Second = LETTERS[1:nrow(.)],
         Third = as.character(1:nrow(.))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(First, Second, Third), names_to = "layer", values_to = "label") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Case, y = factor(layer, c("Third", "Second", "First")))) +
  # Add Table Style
  geom_tile(fill = "blue", alpha = .4, color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = label)) +
  # Remove expansion of axsis
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0))) +
  labs(y = "", x = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank(), panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "mm")) +
  facet_grid(~Class)

p1 / p2 +  plot_layout(heights = c(8, 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful, do you see a way to do the same in a table shape?

Comment: Hi @Sam. I just added an edit to my post. To give the plot a more table like shape and look I added a geom_tile and removed the spacing. I also checked out whether it is possible to ad boxes around the axis labels. Unfortuntely this seems not to be the case. If you want a real table style with all options to style the table then I'm afraid you have to dive more deeply into the grid package and using grid.arrange to glue the plot and table. See e.g. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html.

Comment: Hi @Stefan Thanks a lot it's very good idea. there is only that it is difficult to align the characters in the table to the ticks of the x axis of the graph when manipulating the font size.. I added some space and adjust the font size so it looks acceptable. I will try also with grid graphics as you mentioned.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, (as in my comment above), this may help you. You just need to name your graph and add the labels in loop and render outside the loop.

```
  ...
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,6), "lines"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15))  +

  scale_x_discrete(labels = paste(1:5 , '\n' ,  10:15,  sep = '')) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off" , xlim = c(1, 5) )

  label = NULL
  ordinal <- c('first','second','third','fourth','fifth','sixth','seventh','eighth','ninth','tenth')
for (i in 1:5) {

  label <- paste(label, '\n', ordinal[i])



}
g1 <- g1 + geom_text(data = df[df$Class == 'Class1',],x = -1 , y = -3, 

          label= label , size = 4)

g1
```

This is what I get as a result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I tried this as well, but the y axis values are not fixed, because the analysis is on multiple objects and will yield different y values.